# How to unset dynamically generated multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to delete an array whereby one of its values..(time) meet a specific condition. \The code I'm currently working with looks like this:

```
foreach($_SESSION as $key) {
   foreach($key['time'] as $keys=>$value){
      if(condition){
      unset($key);
   }
}
}
```

The array looks like this.

```
Array
    (
[form1] => Array
    (
        [hash] => lFfKBKiCTG6vOQDa8c7n
        [time] => 1401067044
    )

[form5] => Array
    (
        [hash] => TTmLVODDEkI1NrRnAbfB
        [time] => 1401063352
    )

[form4] => Array
    (
        [hash] => XCVOvrGbhuqAZehBmwoD
        [time] => 1401063352
    )
```

I tried to adapt solutions from these pages but didn't work.

[Remove element in multidimensional array and save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559651/remove-element-in-multidimensional-array-and-save)

[PHP - unset in a multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260468/php-unset-in-a-multidimensional-array)

[PHP How to Unset Member of Multidimensional Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17883428/php-how-to-unset-member-of-multidimensional-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to unset the values inside it, a simple single foreach will suffice. Consider this example:

```
$values = array(
    'form1' => array('hash' => 'lFfKBKiCTG6vOQDa8c7n', 'time' => 1401067044),
    'form5' => array('hash' => 'TTmLVODDEkI1NrRnAbfB', 'time' => 1401063352),
    'form4' => array('hash' => 'XCVOvrGbhuqAZehBmwoD', 'time' => 1401063352),
);
$needle = 1401067044;
foreach($values as $key => &$value) {
    if($value['time'] == $needle) {
        // if you want to remove this key pair use this
        unset($values[$key]['time']);
        // if you just want to remove the value inside it
        $value['time'] = null;
        // if you want to remove all of this entirely
        unset($values[$key]);
    }
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/eY7M2f)

Comment: I get `Notice: Undefined index: time in C:\wamp\www\email.php on line 54` on line `if($value['time'] == $needle) {`

Comment: @dotman14 maybe a mismatch on your array values as it works okay here (http://codepad.viper-7.com/eY7M2f) (also added fiddle on anwser)

Answer (score 2):

Unsetting in a for loop can lead to issues, its easier and better to use `array_filter` which is optimized for this kind of problem. Here is how to do it with your example. [ideone running code](http://ideone.com/VZVbhT)

```
<?php


$ar = Array(
  "form1" => Array
  (
    "hash" => 'lFfKBKiCTG6vOQDa8c7n',
    "time" => '1401067044'
   ),
  "form5" => Array
  (
    "hash" => 'TTmLVODDEkI1NrRnAbfB',
    "time" => '1401063352'
   ),
  "form4" => Array
  (
    "hash" => 'XCVOvrGbhuqAZehBmwoD',
    "time" => '1401063352'
   )
);

$condition = '1401067044';
$newArray = array_filter($ar, function($form) use ($condition) {
    if (!isset($form['time'])) {
      return true;
    }
    return $form['time'] != $condition;
});

var_export($newArray);
```

[array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do

```
unset($_SESSION[$key])
```

However as mentioned by Victory, `array_filter` is probably a better approach to this.

Comment: PHP does not always duplicate an array it is about to iterate over.

Comment: Please read the following: http://nikic.github.io/2011/11/11/PHP-Internals-When-does-foreach-copy.html - nikic is a PHP core developer. "Still some people don’t like to use it, because they think it is slow. One reason usually named is that foreach copies the array it iterates."

Comment: Sometimes it does some copying, not always.  C.f. http://nikic.github.io/2011/11/11/PHP-Internals-When-does-foreach-copy.html

Comment: Removed all references to array being copied. Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your values are stored in `$_SESSION`

```
foreach($_SESSION as $key => $value) {
    if(isset($value['time']) && $value['time'] < 1401063352) {
        unset($_SESSION[$key]);
    }
}
```

If you are storing your values in $_SESSION you may want to consider storing them in a subfield like $_SESSION['myForms'] so if you need to add other values to your session you can easily access only the values you need.

Comment: There are fields there already `$_SESSION['form1']`, `$_SESSION['form2']` etc

Comment: @dotman14 suppose you want to store some other information in your session, i.e. $_SESSION['user_id'], then it would be useful if all your forms were stored under $_SESSION['myForms'] i.e. $_SESSION['myForms']['form1'], $_SESSION['myForms']['form2'] etc. so you could iterate over only forms and not all session values

Comment: Okay, I get it. The solution about deleted all arrays.